# Что следует употребить: "оттого" или "от того"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости **от того**, что ты получаешь
именно то, что хочешь.

Положительные эмоции **оттого**, что твой интерьер изначально получится таким, как ты хочешь, стильным и гармоничным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложенные варианты имеют назывной характер, то есть соответствуют словосочетаниям.

Если они используются в предложении, **то их нужно различать,** то есть мы должны определить вид придаточного предложения: (1) местоименно-определительное (от того, что) или (2) обстоятельственное со значением причины (оттого что).

Сравним два варианта:

**Вариант 1.**

(1) Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости **от того, что** ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.

(2) Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости,  **оттого что** (потому что) ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.

Можно расчленить союз: Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости  **оттого, что** ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.

Как мы видим, **оба вида придаточного подходят.**

**Вариант 2.**

(1) Чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости **от того, что** ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь, не покидало меня.

(2)Чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости, **оттого что** ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь, не покидало меня.  **Это предложение некорректно.**

**Вывод**

Оба варианта возможны не всегда. В частности, **в середине предложения может находиться только местоименно-определительное придаточное.**

Answer (score 3):

Ой-ё, да оба варианта возможны - и "потому", и от конкретного "того".

Но с "потому" меньше мороки, оно как-то беспроигрышней и не требует допобъяснений.

Выбираем в первом случае слитное:

*Чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости оттого, что ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.*

---

Абсолютно то же и со вторым предложением, но тут, мне кажется, акцент на "том", потому предпочтём раздельное написание:

*Положительные эмоции от того, что твой интерьер изначально получится таким, как ты хочешь, стильным и гармоничным.*

---

А в общем и целом - это авторская воля, на чём делать акцент. Формальной ошибки сторонний глаз не обнаружит.

Answer (score 0):

> Чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости [от того/оттого], что ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.

Это не все предложение, а только его часть, поэтому нельзя дать однозначный ответ. При принятии решения советую воспользоваться подходом, предложенным в ответе Ксении.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Грамоты:

> [Вопрос № 281500](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281500)
>   Как разграничить оттого что и от того что? Чем руководствоваться при написании? Но еще страшнее становилось (от)того, что я не понимала, откуда ждать опасности.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Союз оттого что можно заменить синонимичным союзом потому что. 
>   Запятая может ставиться перед союзом или между его частями. Ср.: я счастлива оттого, что он сказал мне эти слова / я счастлива, оттого что он сказал мне эти слова (= я счастлива потому, что он сказал мне эти слова / я счастлива, потому что он сказал мне эти слова) – многое зависит от того, что он скажет (здесь сочетание предлога с местоимением от того, заменить союзом потому что невозможно, запятая может быть поставлена только перед что, на что падает ударение).
>   В приведенном Вами примере используется союз оттого что.

Получается, что раздельно пишется в таком варианте:

*Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости от того, чт**О** ты получаешь, а получаешь ты именно то, что хочешь.*

А здесь только слитное:

*Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости оттого, что ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь.*

Дополнение. Еще ответы Грамоты:

> Вопрос № 223617
>    Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, как пишется "от того что" в данном предложении:"Спал он не долго и проснулся от того, что крупные капли дождя зашлёпали по лицу". Спасибо!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Правильно слитное написание.
>
> Вопрос № 213205
>      Здравствуйте! К вопросу № 213198. Я вас спрашивала о постановке запятой между двумя союзами ТО и НЕЗАВИСИМО ОТ ТОГО ЧТО, а не где ставится запятая: перед всем сложным союзом или перед второй его частью. Ответьте, пожалуйста на вопрос! Спасибо!!! Срочно!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Возможные варианты: *Если стоимость была учтена, то независимо от того, что оплата произведена, денежные средства не уменьшают базу* и *Если стоимость была учтена, то, независимо от того что оплата произведена, денежные средства не уменьшают базу.*

Получается, что критерий слитного написания:  *от()того что* можно заменить синонимичным союзом *потому что*. Критерий раздельного написания: сочетание предлога с местоимением *от того* нельзя заменить на *потому что*.

Comment: Думаю, что раздельное написание тоже возможно:Ты испытываешь чувство глубокого удовлетворения и радости от того, что ты получаешь именно то, что хочешь. Здесь ОТ ТОГО - указательное слово, а ЧТО  союз (не союзное слово). И в другом вопросе тоже можно писать раздельно: Как назвать человека или его качество, когда ему становится легче от того, что другим тоже плохо?

Comment: @Sharon Вы хотите сказать, что если есть управление типа "от чего" (в наших примерах: страшно от чего-то страшного; проснулся от чего-то шумного; радость от чего-то радостного), то можно писать раздельно?

Comment: Ну да,  это изъяснительное придаточное, оно раскрывает содержание указательного местоимения. Кстати, у меня там неверно написано, что определительное.