# Человеку становится легче оттого, что другим тоже плохо, — как это называется?

Tags: лексика

Как назвать человека или его качество, когда ему становится легче от того, что другим тоже плохо?))

Comment: @alexsms  Садистское удовольствие заглушает его страдания? Ну, Вы далеко зашли!

Comment: "Легче от того" или "легче оттого"? По-моему , нужно писать слитно.

Comment: @alexsms пожалуйста, давайте ответы в ответах. https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/178412

Comment: @М_Г  Помните, мы разбирали эту тему. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445757/Что-следует-употребить-оттого-или-от-того

Comment: @Sharon, Тема сложная, я добавил там свой ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Такое качество можно назвать **подсознательным эгоизмом.**

Подсознательный эгоизм сложился у человека очень давно, он был необходим ему **для выживания в конкурентных условиях** (речь идет о том, что иногда называют "мозгом рептилии").

**Вот как это выглядит**.

Никто не должен быть впереди. Если я счастлив, то другие тоже пусть будут счастливы, но меньше, чем я. Если мне плохо, то другим не должно быть хорошо. Иначе они выживут, а я нет.

Цивилизованный человек способен управлять своими эмоциями и подавлять в себе проявление подсознательного эгоизма, но не у всех это получается.

ЭГОИЗМ, -а; м. [франц. egoisme от лат. ego - я] Поведение, целиком определяемое мыслью о собственной пользе, выгоде, предпочтение своих интересов интересам других людей; себялюбие

Answer (score 0):

Строго говоря, это не некое качество, а его проявление. Но проявление это вряд ли можно подвести под одно какое-то качество. Возможно, это в некоторой степени проявление эгоизма, как описала его Sharon, возможно — завистливости: человек, которому плохо, завидует тем, у кого дела идут хорошо; когда он узнает, что другим тоже плохо, ему становится легче.

А может, этот человек — философ, который понимает, что все относительно. Видя, что другим не лучше, чем ему, он пересматривает свое отношение к происходящему, и ему становится легче.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, это злорадство, если проявляется постоянно.

А вообще, нужна ситуация, причина, по которой человек злорадствует. Злорадствуют ведь и так называемые энергетические вампиры, и просто завистливые недоброжелательные люди,и обычный человек иногда испытывает облегчение, когда ему плохо, а кому-то ещё хуже: ну, значит, справимся, вон сосед вообще... и ничего, живёт, слава богу.

Comment: Сомневаюсь я однако! Ваш герой радуется, а нашему просто полегчало. Или, по-Вашему, такая радость заглушает его страдания?

Comment: По вопросу автора непонятно, каков герой, сама ситуация очень общая, лёгкость на душе часто ассоциируется с радостью. Мне вот кажется, что это вообще не отдельное качество человека (если оно не повторяется постоянно), а просто некая ситуация, когда обычный человек без отрицательных качеств испытывает облегчение: не один я такой бедолага, все такие. Если все, то и нормально, не стоит переживать.

Comment: В невзгодах наших лучших друзей мы находим нечто даже приятное для себя (Ларошфуко, Максимы и моральные размышления). Это же злорадство?